# Translating sentences into pig latin

Tags: python

SO i have this assignment to translate multiple words into pig latin. assume that the user will always input lowercase and only letters and spaces.

```
#----------------global variables
sentence = input("What do you want to translate into piglattin? ")
sentence = list(sentence)
sentence.insert(0, ' ')
length = len(sentence)
sentence.append(' ')
pigLattin = sentence
false = 0
true = 1
consonant = []

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
j = 0
x = 0
y = 0


#----------------main functions
def testSpace(sentence, i):
    if sentence[i] == ' ':
        a = true
    else:
        a = false
    return a

def testVowel(sentence, i):
    if sentence[i] == 'a' or sentence[i] == 'e' or sentence[i] == 'i' or sentence[i] == 'o' or sentence[i] == 'u' or sentence[i] == 'y':
        b = true
    else:
        b = false
    return b

def testStartWord(sentence, i):
    x = 0
    if sentence[i].isalpha() and sentence[i-1] == ' ':
        c = true
        x = 1
    if x == 1 and sentence[i] != 'a' and sentence[i] != 'e' and sentence[i] != 'i' and sentence[i] != 'o' and sentence[i] != 'u' and sentence[i] != 'y':
        c = true
    else:
        c = false
    return c
def testWordEnd(sentence, i):
    if sentence[i].isalpha() and sentence[i+1] == ' ':
        d = true
    else:
        d = false
    return d


#----------------main loop
for i in range(1,length):
    x = 0
    space = testSpace(sentence, i)
    vowel = testVowel(sentence, i)
    word = testStartWord(sentence, i)
    end = testWordEnd(sentence, i)

    if vowel == false and space == false and word == true:
        e = i
        consonant.append(sentence[i])
        pigLattin.pop(e)
        f = f + 1

    if end == true:
        consonant.append('a')
        consonant.append('y')
        consLength = len(consonant)

        for x in range(consLength):
            y = i + j - f
            pigLattin.insert(y,consonant[x])
            j = j + 1

        del consonant[:]

pigLength = len(pigLattin)   
for b in range (pigLength):
    print(pigLattin[b], end='')
```

this is what i have so far.  it gets kinda messy when trying to remove items.  im sort of stuck here and its not working.

OK i got it working now this is an updated version

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
words =  sentence.split()

count = 0

def find_vowel(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
       if word[i] in vowels:
         return i
    return -1

for word in words:
  vowel = find_vowel(word)

  if(vowel == -1):
    print(word, ' ', end='')

  elif(vowel == 0):
    print(word + "ay", ' ', end='')

  else:
    print(word[vowel:] + word[:vowel] + "ay", ' ', end='')
```

Comment: `x="pig";print "%s%say"%(x[1:],x[0])`

Comment: Here is a list of things you should do.  First ignore case and punctuation to start.  Then write a function that works on a single word.  Use compact notation for `if letter in 'aeiouy'`.  Now write a function that takes a sentence and uses `sentence.split(' ')` and `' '.join(new_sentence)` to split into words, use your first function, and recombine into one string. Then work on adding case and punctuation back in if you want. Hint: each function should be like 5 lines in the first version.

Comment: If you want flexibility in input, you can always use `str.lower()` to convert the string "str" to lowercase character.

Comment: Stack overflow shouldn't be how you get your homework done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `testSpace` eliminate the spaces by using `sentence = sentence.split()`. This will split all your words into strings in a list. Then iterate through the words in your list.

Instead of using `testStartWord`, use an if statement:

```
for word in sentence:
  if word[0] in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
    word[:(len(word)-1)] = word[0]
  #More Code...
```

At the end, where you print the output, use `print sentence.join()`

Comment: thanks for the help i got it working now using your suggestions and it runs smooth and much more simple

Comment: those are some really small tabs!

Comment: you will want the sentence to be joined with spaces, sentence.join(' ') will do that

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate version. I use a regular expression to find words in the input string, pass them to a callback function, and substitute them back into the original string. This allows me to preserve numbers, spacing and punctuation:

```
import re
import sys

# Python 2/3 compatibility shim
inp = input if sys.hexversion >= 0x3000000 else raw_input

VOWELS = set('aeiouyAEIOUY')
YS = set('yY')

def pig_word(word):
    """
    Given a word, convert it to Pig Latin
    """
    if hasattr(word, 'group'):
        # pull the text out of a regex match object
        word = word.group()

    # find the first vowel and what it is
    vowel, where = None, None
    for i,ch in enumerate(word):
        if ch in VOWELS:
            vowel, where = ch, i
            break

    if vowel is None:
        # No vowels found
        return word
    elif where == 0 and vowel not in YS:
        # Starts with a vowel - end in 'way'
        #   (leading y is treated as a consonant)
        return word + 'way'
    else:
        # Starts with consonants - move to end and follow with 'ay'

        # check capitalization
        uppercase = word.isupper() and len(word) > 1
        titlecase = word[:1].isupper() and not uppercase

        # rearrange word
        word = word[where:] + word[:where] + 'ay'

        # repair capitalization
        if uppercase:
            word = word.upper()
        elif titlecase:
            # don't use str.title() because it screws up words with apostrophes
            word = word[:1].upper() + word[1:].lower()

        return word

def pig_latin(s, reg=re.compile('[a-z\']+', re.IGNORECASE)):
    """
    Translate a sentence into Pig Latin
    """
    # find each word in the sentence, pass it to pig_word, and insert the result back into the string
    return reg.sub(pig_word, s)

def main():
    while True:
        s = inp('Enter a sentence to translate (or Enter to quit): ')
        if s.strip():
            print(pig_latin(s))
            print('')
        else:
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

then

```
Enter a sentence to translate (or Enter to quit):
>>> Hey, this is really COOL!  Let's try it 3 or 4 times...
Eyhay, isthay isway eallyray OOLCAY!  Et'slay ytray itway 3 orway 4 imestay...
```